# Reading lines in textbox individually

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I am trying read each line  in a textbox individually and check if it contains a certain string. This will be used in the textchanged event of the textbox to check for a certain string and it will execute it's corresponding code if found.

I cant get it working right though. Here is my code.

```
    Dim txt As FastColoredTextBox = TryCast(page.Controls(0), FastColoredTextBox)
        For Each line As Line In txt.Lines
            If CBool(InStr(line.ToString(), "<vb>")) Then
                txt.Language = Language.VB
            End If
```

Comment: What is it doing and what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am guessing you're using the FastColoredTextBox from the CodeProject.com site, right?

Try splitting the Text of the text box into its corresponding lines first:

```
Dim txt As FastColoredTextBox = TryCast(page.Controls(0), FastColoredTextBox)
Dim Lines as string() = txt.Text.Split(VbCrLf)
For Each line As String In txt.Lines
  CBool(InStr(line, "<vb>")) Then
  txt.Language = Language.VB
End If
```

Comment: -1 This creates an unnecessary array of strings already present in the control. The Text property is here to use.

Answer (score 1):

The FastColoredTextBox.Lines is a List(Of String) so you could simply loop on the Lines in this way

```
Dim txt As FastColoredTextBox = TryCast(page.Controls(0), FastColoredTextBox) 
For Each line As String In txt.Lines 
   If line.IndexOf("<vb>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 Then 
      txt.Language = Language.VB 
      Exit For ' If this is all you have to do exit immediatly
   End If 
Next
```

EDIT:
The Exit For allows to break the loop without searching on subsequent lines that are of no interest. Of course, if you have other `if` then the Exit For should be removed.
Also note that in my answer you don't have to create an unnecessary array of all the strings already in the control.
And as last note, why use the old style Instr (VB6) when now we have a rich bag of string tools

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a question though, if I have multiple if statements in the loop should I still add the exit for? I have never used the exit for statement so I am wondering what purpose it serves.

Comment: I have inserted an Exit For to break out of the loop assuming that you were interested only in finding the line for the Script Language. The Exit For allows to break the loop without searching on subsequent lines that are of no interest. Of course, if you have other if then the Exit For should be removed. Please note that the accepted answer, has in my opinion a severe performance problem. It creates an unnecessary array of all the strings already in your control.

Comment: Performance is a big issue in my application, I can't afford to lose any. My only problem with using this is I get an error: value of type string cannot be converted to fastcoloredtextboxns.line

Comment: On which line do you get this error? In my answer or in your question?

Comment: in you answer on this line:For Each line As Line In txt.Lines. It wasn't working in mine either I should of changed that.

Comment: That line is the same from your original code. I have searched the help of FastColoredTextBox and I have found that Lines is a List(Of String) so I have changed my answer.

Comment: Would I have to add that something like this?

Comment: Do I have to add the list(of string) into the code aswell? I know my code is wrong because it would mean every line is a list.

Comment: Dim txt As FastColoredTextBox = TryCast(page.Controls(0), FastColoredTextBox)
        For Each line As List(Of String) In txt.Lines
            If line.IndexOf("<vb>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 Then
                txt.Language = Language.VB
            End If
            If line.IndexOf("<c#>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 Then
                txt.Language = Language.CSharp
            End If
            If line.IndexOf("<javascript>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 Then
                txt.Language = Language.JS
            End If
        Next

Comment: If I add the code you added, it still has the same error. On:For Each line As String In txt.Lines

Comment: Tried that code with their sample. Works as expected. I can't help but I repeat again `txt.Lines` is a `List(Of String)`. You iterate on a List(Of String) using the syntax provided

Comment: Ok so weird thing is I am not getting any errors although it only changes it twice, just as if I was using instr(txt.text, "<vb>"). Like I said it could have multiples of each tag. Is it working for you multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Why you're going in that long way, I did it now with the following short easy code:

```
For i = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Lines.Count)-1
    If TextBox1.Lines(i).ToString.StartsWith("OS Version:") Then
        Label9.Text = TextBox1.Lines(i).ToString
        Exit For
      Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```